# Query params in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I am using `React Router` & I have a nested route which have a query parameter called `?q` & my routing code looks like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={TopNavContainer}>
    <Route path="search?que=:q" component={SearchContainer} />
</Route>
```

but when I try to access my route as `http://localhost:8000?q=machine`
It only loads the content of the parent container which is `TopNavContainer`.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Vaibhav

Comment: I think no need to specify query param in route configurations. You can easily remove **?que=:q**. and you can catch query params in**SeachContainer** by **this.props.location.query** or use in**componentWillReceiveProps** by **nextProps.location.query** each time query changed

Comment: ok I will try that

Comment: yeah this worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could also be the case that you have forgot to render any child component corresponding to route changes inside parent main component which in your case is `TopNavContainer`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class TopNavContainer extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="topNavContainer">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

For this route configuration

```
<Route path="/" component={TopNavContainer}>
    <Route path="search?que=:q" component={SearchContainer} />
</Route>
```

Your url (http://localhost:8000?q=machine) don't match the path, the correct should be http://localhost:8000/search?que=machine

As a recommendation for SEO, the url could be

```
<Route path="search/:q" component={SearchContainer} />
```

that match http://localhost:8000/search/machine

Comment: This is a route parameter. The OP is looking for query parameters.